# Upload as a File Check box not showing

Tags: sitecore-client, media-library

I am using Sitecore 9.1 and I want to configure the Media Item save behavior. I want to save all Media Items in File Systems instead of Database. As of now i want to store in the same server.

I have enabled the Media.UploadAsFiles to true as
 `<setting name="Media.UploadAsFiles" value="true" />`

and DisableFileMedia is false by default as
 `<setting name="Media.DisableFileMedia" value="false" />`

But still i am not getting the Checkbox to select and upload the Media Item as File.

Please refer the screenshot as

[image]

Comment: Did you try to actually upload an asset and test where it goes?

Comment: Its storing in Database,not in file system.

Comment: Don't undo my edits. We do not include Sitecore version information in question titles.

Comment: @G.AliAnsari - how did you find the media item in the DB? What table/how'd you get the Id to put in WHERE?

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behaviour.

You have configured upload as `<setting name="Media.UploadAsFiles" value="true" />` and you expect to see all four options during upload like this:

[image]

This is false assumption.

As you have configured it to always upload media files to file system, there won't be anymore `Upload as files` option.

Do not forget to conclude your setup by specifying `Media.FileFolder` path. Uploaded files will be stored in this folder
`<setting name=”Media.FileFolder” value=”/App_Data/MediaFiles”>`

Comment: I have tested after changing the path also. But its not showing.

Comment: It is not showing because you set `<setting name="Media.UploadAsFiles" value="true" />` ! Set `<setting name="Media.UploadAsFiles" value="false" />` and then you will see that checkbox.

Comment: @G.AliAnsari - in other words... Media.UploadAsFiles=true is basically saying that it will always be a file anyway, so why both showing the checkbox? If you want the checkbox, change it to false so users have the choice.